# How to extract PLSR coefficients as for glmnet using tidymodels

Tags: r, coefficients, tidymodels, pls

I tuned a glmnet regression model and extracted the coefficients as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63087592/how-to-extract-glmnet-coefficients-produced-by-tidymodels). That works wonderfully. However, when I use the same form of coefficient extraction for PLSR with mixOmics engine, I obtain single values per term and component as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64254295/predictor-importance-for-pls-model-trained-with-tidymodels). For further external use I need the coefficients of PLSR in the first form. I can achieve this by using the optimal hyperparamterset with the `plsr()` function from the pls package and then extracting it with `coef()` as shown at the end of the code below. However, I would like to avoid this extra step because I cannot pass parameters like `predictor_prop` to `plsr` and thus results may vary.

Is there a more elegant way to extract the overall model coefficients of the PLSR as for glmnet or can I calculate them from the component values?

```
library(tidymodels)
library(plsmod)

data(Chicago)
Chicago <- Chicago %>% select(ridership, Clark_Lake, Austin, Harlem)

# create cross-validation dataset
folds <- vfold_cv(Chicago)

# create recipe
rec <- recipe(ridership ~ ., Chicago) %>% 
  step_normalize(all_predictors()) %>%
  prep(training = Chicago)

# define model
mod <- parsnip::pls(mode = "regression", 
                    num_comp = tune(), 
                    predictor_prop = tune()) %>% 
  set_engine("mixOmics")

# define workflow
wf <- workflow() %>%
  add_recipe(rec) %>%
  add_model(mod)

# run grid tuning
set.seed(123)
res <- tune_grid(wf, resamples = folds, grid = 5)

# get best model
res_best <- res %>% select_best("rmse")

# fit best model and extract coefficients
wf %>% 
  finalize_workflow(res_best) %>%
  fit(Chicago) %>%
  extract_fit_parsnip() %>% 
  tidy()

# extracting coefficients using plsr from pls package and coef function
p <- pls::plsr(ridership ~ ., data = Chicago, scale = T, center = T, ncomp = 3)
coef(p, intercept = T)
```

Thank you for the awesome tidymodels framework and everyone who makes it what it is!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell you are doing the correct thing.

The `coef()` functions only shows you the result for `3 comps` but you can get the same result by adding `filter(component == 3)` in the following code

```r
wf %>% 
  finalize_workflow(res_best) %>%
  fit(Chicago) %>%
  extract_fit_parsnip() %>% 
  tidy() %>%
  filter(component == 3)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 4
#>   term       value type       component
#>   <chr>      <dbl> <chr>          <dbl>
#> 1 Clark_Lake     0 predictors         3
#> 2 Austin         1 predictors         3
#> 3 Harlem         0 predictors         3
#> 4 Y              1 outcomes           3
```

The reason why you are getting 0s and 1s is because the hyper parameter tuned values of `predictor_prop` is quite low, giving you are sparse representation

```r
library(tidymodels)
library(plsmod)

data(Chicago)
Chicago <- Chicago %>% select(ridership, Clark_Lake, Austin, Harlem)

# create cross-validation dataset
folds <- vfold_cv(Chicago)

# create recipe
rec <- recipe(ridership ~ ., Chicago) %>% 
  step_normalize(all_predictors()) %>%
  prep(training = Chicago)

# define model
mod <- parsnip::pls(mode = "regression", 
                    num_comp = tune(), 
                    predictor_prop = tune()) %>% 
  set_engine("mixOmics")

# define workflow
wf <- workflow() %>%
  add_recipe(rec) %>%
  add_model(mod)

# run grid tuning
set.seed(123)
res <- tune_grid(wf, resamples = folds, grid = 5)

# get best model
res_best <- res %>% select_best("rmse")

res_best
#> # A tibble: 1 × 3
#>   predictor_prop num_comp .config             
#>            <dbl>    <int> <chr>               
#> 1         0.0869        3 Preprocessor1_Model1

# fit best model and extract coefficients
wf %>% 
  finalize_workflow(res_best) %>%
  fit(Chicago) %>%
  extract_fit_parsnip() %>%
  tidy()
#> # A tibble: 12 × 4
#>    term       value type       component
#>    <chr>      <dbl> <chr>          <dbl>
#>  1 Clark_Lake     1 predictors         1
#>  2 Clark_Lake     0 predictors         2
#>  3 Clark_Lake     0 predictors         3
#>  4 Austin         0 predictors         1
#>  5 Austin         0 predictors         2
#>  6 Austin         1 predictors         3
#>  7 Harlem         0 predictors         1
#>  8 Harlem        -1 predictors         2
#>  9 Harlem         0 predictors         3
#> 10 Y              1 outcomes           1
#> 11 Y              1 outcomes           2
#> 12 Y              1 outcomes           3

wf %>% 
  finalize_workflow(
    tibble(predictor_prop = 0, num_comp = 3)
  ) %>%
  fit(Chicago) %>%
  extract_fit_parsnip() %>%
  tidy()
#> # A tibble: 12 × 4
#>    term       value type       component
#>    <chr>      <dbl> <chr>          <dbl>
#>  1 Clark_Lake     1 predictors         1
#>  2 Clark_Lake     0 predictors         2
#>  3 Clark_Lake     0 predictors         3
#>  4 Austin         0 predictors         1
#>  5 Austin         0 predictors         2
#>  6 Austin         1 predictors         3
#>  7 Harlem         0 predictors         1
#>  8 Harlem        -1 predictors         2
#>  9 Harlem         0 predictors         3
#> 10 Y              1 outcomes           1
#> 11 Y              1 outcomes           2
#> 12 Y              1 outcomes           3

wf %>% 
  finalize_workflow(
    tibble(predictor_prop = 0.5, num_comp = 3)
  ) %>%
  fit(Chicago) %>%
  extract_fit_parsnip() %>%
  tidy()
#> # A tibble: 12 × 4
#>    term        value type       component
#>    <chr>       <dbl> <chr>          <dbl>
#>  1 Clark_Lake  0.908 predictors         1
#>  2 Clark_Lake  0     predictors         2
#>  3 Clark_Lake  0     predictors         3
#>  4 Austin      0.419 predictors         1
#>  5 Austin     -0.859 predictors         2
#>  6 Austin     -0.406 predictors         3
#>  7 Harlem      0     predictors         1
#>  8 Harlem     -0.513 predictors         2
#>  9 Harlem      0.914 predictors         3
#> 10 Y           1     outcomes           1
#> 11 Y           1     outcomes           2
#> 12 Y           1     outcomes           3

wf %>% 
  finalize_workflow(
    tibble(predictor_prop = 1, num_comp = 3)
  ) %>%
  fit(Chicago) %>%
  extract_fit_parsnip() %>%
  tidy()
#> # A tibble: 12 × 4
#>    term        value type       component
#>    <chr>       <dbl> <chr>          <dbl>
#>  1 Clark_Lake  0.593 predictors         1
#>  2 Clark_Lake  0.738 predictors         2
#>  3 Clark_Lake  0.321 predictors         3
#>  4 Austin      0.576 predictors         1
#>  5 Austin     -0.111 predictors         2
#>  6 Austin     -0.810 predictors         3
#>  7 Harlem      0.562 predictors         1
#>  8 Harlem     -0.665 predictors         2
#>  9 Harlem      0.491 predictors         3
#> 10 Y           1     outcomes           1
#> 11 Y           1     outcomes           2
#> 12 Y           1     outcomes           3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, Emil. Unfortunately, even if I vary `predictor_prop` and filter by component, the result is totally different than when I run `coef(pls::plsr(ridership ~ ., data = Chicago, ncomp = 3), intercept = TRUE)`, which would give me the coefficients in the desired form. Do you have any idea if there is another method I can use to extract the yintercept and coefficients from the tidymodels workflow?